# Trouble with Async Task and RoutedEventHandler in WPF/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, routed-events

I have an User Control with a Button which is used from a Window with a `RoutedEventHandler`:

**UserControl:**

```
public event RoutedEventHandler IniciarPLC_Click;
private void BtnIniciarPLC_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   .....
   if (IniciarPLC_Click != null)
   {
        IniciarPLC_Click(this, new RoutedEventArgs());
   }
   ......
}
```

**Window:**

*XAML:*

```
<ucUserControl x:Name="cntBarraHerramientas"  IniciarPLC_Click="CntBarraHerramientas_IniciarPLC_Click"/>
```

*C#:*

```
private void CntBarraHerramientas_IniciarPLC_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ....       
}
```

But I need call to an `async` method in `CntBarraHerramientas_IniciarPLC_Click`, so I changed the `void` return type by `async Task` and call the method with `await`:

```
private async Task CntBarraHerramientas_IniciarPLC_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await AsyncMethod(...);
}
```

And I have this error:

> Could not create a 'IniciarPLC_Click' from the text 'CntBarraHerramientas_IniciarPLC_Click'. '
> ArgumentException: You cannot link to the target method because its security transparency or signature is not compatible with that of the delegated type.

The question is how to I do call an `async` Method with `RoutedEventHandler`? Because the `async` method calling from a Button click event work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Event handler should be `async void`. It's one of the few places where you would have `async void` instead of `async Task`

Comment: Yes, with private async void CntBarraHerramientas_IniciarPLC_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) work, Thanks.